# PHP wamp server error

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, wamp, wampserver

I am pretty new on php particularly wamp. I got to access a live wamp server. PHP version 5.2.5. But my app needs to use PHP 5.3.0, so I just uninstall wamp from live server and install new wamp with PHP 5.3.0. Now the new installed server is not getting started. On starting it gives error that

> php_pdo.dll file was not found. RE-installing app could fix problem.

Also the icon is still yellow. I want to know what the problem is with server and how this fix?  Also is there some thing because of previously installed wamp server?
Pleas do tell me as it was live server so I need to fix things as quickly as possible.

Comment: 2.5.5 -> 5.3.0. It's like a time machine :).

Comment: sorry abuot miswritten it is 5.2.5 and 5.3.0 in question

Answer (score 5):

Having PHP 5.3 you no longer need to have to activate PDO through the php.ini file. That means you're good to go using PDO natively.

> This step is not necessary for PHP 5.3
>   and above, as a DLL is no longer
>   required for PDO.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

Answer (score 2):

It means that you didn't load the PDO extension. Do a right click on the WAMP icon in your task bar and under PHP menu enable the PDO extension. Restart wamp and the problem should be solved.

Comment: Hello there. thanks for quick response. I tried php extensions and checked there. php_pdo was already selected and if I try to deselect it then it gives error "internal error. Exception: service is not started so operation could not be executed"

Comment: Do you have the dll in  you wamp folder wamp/bin/php/php5.3.0/ext/php_pdo.dll

Comment: no I have other dll files like php_pdo_mysql.dll,php_pdo_oci.dll etc, but not php_pdo.dll. Also I have running wamp on my local machine and works fine even there is no php_pdo.dll file

Answer (score 1):

Click on the wamp server icon on your taskbar, go to Apache and you will find Test Port 80 in there. That will show whether port 80 is available or not. If not, go to httpd.conf file which is in the Apache menu of wamp server, find line Listen 80. Change 80 to 88. Restart All Services in wamp and that should work. Let me know if that helped.